# PHP: Using preg_match_all to split csv into usable array

Tags: php, csv, preg-match-all

I'm trying to use preg_match_all in php to pull out the individual pieces of a csv string.

Here's the code I'm currently trying:

```
$csv = "1,2,3,4";
$match = "/^(\d+)(?:,(\d+))*$/";

$matches = array();

preg_match_all($match, $csv, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

What I'm expecting is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1,2,3,4
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
        )
)
```

What I'm getting is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1,2,3,4
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
        )
)
```

I can only modify what's between the '^' and the '$' as this is only a part of the full string.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: When you repeat a capturing group, precedent captures are overwritten by the new. It is the reason why you obtain the last result. Are you sure you need a regex to split a csv? You can use explode instead.

Comment: If I understand correctly the RegEx is b/c the OP is trying to match part of a much larger dataset.

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is extracting column definitions from a SQL statement, but the RegEx statement for that is huge, so I didn't want to post the whole thing here.

Casimir, is there any way around the captures being overwritten that you know of?

Comment: I did some more looking around, and it seems like you can't get around the captures being overwritten.  So this turns into a two-step process where I match the whole list, and then do a second (looped) match on the list using /(\d)+/ to pull out the individual pieces. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Don't do your own CSV parsing.  Use the CSV functionality that is built in to PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

```
function csvToArray( $csvxrow , $delm = ';' , $encl ='"' , $head = true )
{ 
    $csvxrow[0] = chop( $csvxrow[0] ); 
    $csvxrow[0] = str_replace( $encl, '' ,$csvxrow[0] ); 
    $keydata = explode( $delm, $csvxrow[0] ); 
    $keynumb = count( $keydata ); 

    if ( $head === true )
    { 
    $anzdata = count( $csvxrow ); 
    $z = 0; 
    for( $x = 1; $x < $anzdata; $x++ )
    { 
        $csvxrow[$x] = chop( $csvxrow[$x] ); 
        $csvxrow[$x] = str_replace( $encl, '', $csvxrow[$x] ); 
        $csv_data[$x] = explode( $delm, $csvxrow[$x] ); 
        $i = 0; 
        foreach( $keydata as $key )
        { 
            $out[$z][$key] = $csv_data[$x][$i]; 
            $i++;
        }    
        $z++;
        }
    }
    else
    { 
        $i = 0;
        foreach( $csvxrow as $item )
        { 
            $item = chop( $item ); 
            $item = str_replace( $encl, '', $item ); 
            $csv_data = explode( $delm, $item ); 
            for( $y = 0; $y < $keynumb; $y++ )
            { 
               $out[$i][$y] = $csv_data[$y]; 
            }
        $i++;
        }
    }

    return $out; 
}
```

This is what I use. PHP has specific functions for this, but they are not very good.

Set head to false if you do not have the column headings in the CSV.